# Make simple edits on Word document programmatically

Tags: python, ms-word

I want to make some simple edits on a Word document, eg replace all `TEXT` with `text`.

I have tried `python-docx`, but it doesn't let me save only my changes. Instead it makes a new document with default style and saves it with my content.

Is there a good library(Python or other languages) that supports quick edits on docx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit of why you are not able to do simple string replace in docx - a .docx document is a Zip archive in OpenXML format: you have first to uncompress it. Earlier I used to use `zip` to unzip the docx & then search for the text, like so -

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> z = zipfile.ZipFile("yourDocInDocx.docx")
>>> "someText" in z.read("word/document.xml")
True
>>> "random other string" in z.read("word/document.xml")
False
>>> z.close()
```

But later I found this excellent python library for docx - [Python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) which will solve your problem.

```
# Import the module
from docx import *

# Open the .docx file
document = opendocx('yourDocInDocx.docx')

# Search returns true if found    
search(document,'your search string')
```

Comment: how can I save the file again (with either method)?